# AndroidObservables is not recognized by Android Studio

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

This may sound like a stupid question. I have put this in my gradle file

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.+'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.0'
```

but `AndroidObservables` is still not recognized and my code can't get compiled, I already tried syncing Gradle. Any tip? thanks

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/releases/tag/v1.0.0 - **All other APIs have been removed**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something has been moved to **RxLifecycle** at https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle

Depends on what you were using, I suppose.